# Why does gdal use only one core?

Tags: gdal

I run gdal2tiles on debian machine with 4 cores:

```
sudo /usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py -r cubic -a 0,0,0 -z 10-15 /home/adm/topo/ekb.vrt  /var/www/tiles
```

In `htop` I see:

[image]

Why does gdal use only one core in work? 
Gdal version is 2.1.2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because gdal2tiles is single-threaded. You can use a parallelized version available at https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/blob/master/Tiling/gdal2tiles_parallel.py

Comment: There is another version of this file which include enhancements in different forks. Look at https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp/blob/master/gdal2tilesp.py (which is already a fork)